# How to create & format legend in plot_ly while using the split parameter

Tags: r, data-visualization, plotly

I'm trying to create a scatterplot in plot_ly using the split parameter, however I'm having some difficulties with the legend & formatting. Specifically, once I add labels to my chart, more items are added to the legend, the colors don't match, and I can't turn off an entire series with one click. Here's an example:

```r
library(plotly)

plot_ly(mtcars,
        type = "scatter",
        x = ~hp,
        y =~qsec,
        split = ~cyl,
        text = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
  add_text(textposition = "middle right")
```

When you run this code, you can see that the labels do appear for each of the points, however they show in random colors. Additionally, the legend has 6 items. What I want is:

1. The labels should match the color of their series/split (the number
   of cylinders)
2. The legend to have 3 items (4, 6, & 8)
3. When you click
   on one of the items in the legend, it should turn off/on BOTH the
   markers and text labels for that series/split

Thanks a lot for the help!

*In case it helps:*

- R: 3.3.1
- Plotly: 4.5.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `mode` when using type `scatter`.  With the `markers+text` option I believe you don't have the ability to color the text individually.  If you don't mind the text being grey, the solution is:

```
plot_ly(mtcars,
        type = "scatter",
        x = ~hp,
        y = ~qsec,
        split = ~cyl,
        mode = "markers+text",
        text = rownames(mtcars),
        textposition = "middle right")
```

If you want to have it match your request 100%, it gets more complicated and you can't use the `split` parameter.

You have to create individual traces for each cylinder level, first using `mutate` to explicitly include the row names.  You then use `filter` to subset the `mtcars` for each cylinder level.  For each level create 2 traces, a marker and a text.  The `color` would then be equal to the factor level of `cyl`. Finally, you have to group the traces for each cylinder in the legend, hiding the entries you don't need.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)    

plot_ly(filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 4),
        type = "scatter",
        x = ~hp,
        y = ~qsec,
        mode = "markers",
        color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
        legendgroup = '4',
        name = '4',
        textposition = "middle right") %>% 
  add_trace(data = filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 4),
            type = "scatter",
            x = ~hp+2,
            y = ~qsec,
            color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
            mode = "text",
            text = ~names, 
            legendgroup = '4',
            name = '4',
            showlegend = FALSE,
            textposition = "middle right") %>% 
  add_trace(data = filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 6),
          type = "scatter",
          x = ~hp,
          y = ~qsec,
          mode = "markers",
          color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
          legendgroup = '6',
          name = '6',
          textposition = "middle right") %>% 
  add_trace(data = filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 6),
            type = "scatter",
            x = ~hp+2,
            y = ~qsec,
            mode = "text",
            color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
            text = ~names, 
            legendgroup = '6',
            name = '6',
            showlegend = FALSE,
            textposition = "middle right") %>% 
  add_trace(data = filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 8),
            type = "scatter",
            x = ~hp,
            y = ~qsec,
            mode = "markers",
            color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
            legendgroup = '8',
            name = '8',
            textposition = "middle right") %>% 
  add_trace(data = filter(mutate(mtcars, names = rownames(mtcars)), cyl == 8),
            type = "scatter",
            x = ~hp+2,
            y = ~qsec,
            mode = "text",
            color = ~factor(cyl, c(4,6,8)),
            text = ~names, 
            legendgroup = '8', 
            name = '8',
            showlegend = FALSE,
            textposition = "middle right")
```

Comment: Currently, plot_ly is unable to do this, to achieve that functionality, I've edited my original answer to show how to accomplish this.

Comment: Good job! You could leave `text="~names"` for markers traces and add `hoverinfo="none"` for text traces to keep default look and feel